# Could not create task ':GluonApplicationApp:debug'

Tags: gradle, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to run simply the Gluon single scene example. Here is my gradle output:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :GluonApplicationApp
Project :GluonApplicationApp => no module-info.java found

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':GluonApplicationApp'.
> Could not create task ':GluonApplicationApp:debug'.
   > Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported.  Use create() or register() directly instead.  You attempted to replace a task named 'debug', but there is no existing task with that name.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.openjfx:javafx-plugin:0.0.9'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'
```

The JDK version i'm using is JDK 11, and I have tried various gradle versions. For my IDE I use netbeans.

I have been trying to fix this **all day.** Please help

Comment: You are using the "old" `jfxmobile` plugin, which runs on Java 1.8. To use Java/JavaFX 11+, you need to use the new Client plugin. See: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples and https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/

Comment: I tried those instructions. Now, I get this:
https://pastebin.com/LWE74nzA

Comment: The error is clear: `GraalVM installation directory not found. Either set GRAALVM_HOME...` Just do as said here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples#linux-and-android

Comment: $ echo $GRAALVM_HOME Output:
/home/ubuntu/ProgramFiles/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0-dev

It's already set, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: From a terminal, what does `$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/java -version` return?

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.2.0-dev (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.2-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.2.0-dev (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.2-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Ok, then in the same terminal run `export JAVA_HOME=$GRAALVM_HOME`, and then in your project, `mvn clean client:build`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zeE7G8B8
New errors, but at least it got farther

Comment: Can you try Linux first? There are some changes going on for Android, that should be solved soon

Comment: Missing linker libraries: https://pastebin.com/TRmn0sFq

Comment: Solution is provided in the error message, you need to install the missing libraries

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice. Lets' try...

Comment: Linux build works! Android still wont, though...

Comment: Yes, there were breaking changes in GraalVM. Should be fixed really soon (you will need to update to the next GraalVM build once released probably tonight, and a new Client plugin version).

Comment: New Client plugin: 0.1.29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I was using the old Gluon IDE plugin
2. Gluon build 0.1.29-SNAPSHOT fixes the rest of the problems

More details on comments of the question!